# How to make draggable remember it's location in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm learning about the animation and panresponder apis in react native. Following [Animated Drag and Drop with React Native](http://moduscreate.com/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native/) and the [source](https://github.com/crysfel/DragAndDrop/blob/master/app/Viewport.js)

I want to extend the example so that you can drag the circle without having to reset it. Currently the code animates the circle back to the center of the screen and relies on the panresponders dX/dY values.

my best guess is I have to change something in `onPanResponderMove`

```
  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {
    dx: this.state.pan.x,
    dy: this.state.pan.y,
  }]),
```

What do I need to change in the source so if I comment out the `onPanResponderRelease` logic the circle properly drags around the screen?

`getTranslateTransform()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The logic in `onPanResponderRelease` is making it so that if the draggable is not in the dropzone when released, it is reset back to `0,0` ([these are the lines causing it](https://github.com/crysfel/DragAndDrop/blob/master/app/Viewport.js#L36-L39)).

Removing that logic alone isn't all you should do though. You should set the offset and reset the value of `this.state.pan` in `onPanResponderRelease`. To do this you need to track the value.

In `componentDidMount`, add this:

```
this.currentPanValue = {x: 0, y: 0};
this.panListener = this.state.pan.addListener((value) => this.currentPanValue = value);
```

Then, in `componentWillUnmount`:

```
this.state.pan.removeListener(this.panListener);
```

Now that you have the current value, you just add this to the PanResponder:

```
onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
  this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this.currentPanValue.x, y: this.currentPanValue.y});
  this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
},
```

It seems more complicated than it actually is.  Basically you are just setting the offset from 0/0, then setting the value to 0/0 so that when you start moving it again after having released it before, it doesn't jump back to 0/0 before jumping back to where your finger is.  It also makes sure you have its current position...which you will probably need at some point anyways.

Comment: could you elaborate on what `setOffset` does and why it's necessary?

Comment: The line `this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});` in `onPanResponderRelease ` is not necessary. I get the same result with or without that line. I don't see any effect of this line. Should there be one?

Comment: Also: In the code docs of `AnimatedImplementation.js` they write using `Animated.Value.addListener` may cause performance issues. How would you solve this problem with a greater number of circles? - One listener for each circle?

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to track current offset and keep adding it to the pan. So declare this in the constructor `currentPanValue : {x: 0, y: 0},`

And edit the onPanResponderRelease to the following :

```
onPanResponderRelease           : (e, gesture) => {
                this.state.currentPanValue.x += this.state.pan.x._value;
                this.state.currentPanValue.y += this.state.pan.y._value;

                this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this.state.currentPanValue.x, y: this.state.currentPanValue.y});
                this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
            }
```

Incase if you want the final coordinates, you should get it with `this.state.currentPanValue`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only thing you need to change is the onPanResponderRelease function. What you are currently doing is applying the delta of the gesture movement to the initial position of the component. What you want to do is applying it to the position at the end of the last gesture. So you somehow need to save the offset. AnimatedValueXY.setOffset to the rescue!

```
onPanResponderRelease : (e, gesture) => {
    if(this.isDropZone(gesture)){
        this.setState({
            showDraggable : false
        });
    }else{
        this.state.pan.setOffset({
            x: this.state.pan.x._offset + e.dx,
            y: this.state.pan.y._offset + e.dy,
        })
        this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0})
}
```

I'm using the internal _offset variable here because I could find a way to access it via the API. You can off course also just keep track of the offset manually. I didn't test this code yet, but you get the idea.

Comment: There are a few bugs in this code, the main one being that `setOffset` expects an object with x/y: `{x: number, y: number}`.  Also, as you stated, you should track the values and use those.  See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the signature hint. Misread the docs. I don't think there is a need for a listener on the AnimatedValue though. You have all the information you need on release. The only thing is to write the offset down somewhere instead of relying on an internal variable.

Comment: This code does not work. It leads to strange behavior, e.g. after moving it once it jumps back to the center and then the app freezes. Particularly `e.dx` and `e.dy` are zero and after each drag `this.state.pan.x._offset` and `this.state.pan.y._offset` are `0`. However, I'd also suppose there should be a solution without adding a listener. In case you have several freely moving circles this could become a performance issue.