# How can I create a draggable and resizable image in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React-Native and I have been following this tutorial, http://mindthecode.com/getting-started-with-the-panresponder-in-react-native/ along with this [How to make draggable remember it's location in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891728/how-to-make-draggable-remember-its-location-in-react-native) , which create a draggable image that remember the current location.

I want to know if it is possible to create a draggable image with a pinch gesture for zooming in and out (that doesn't goes back to the original size or position).

Comment: Have you found an answer?